# What is SIC/XE immediate addressing mode numeric range?

Tags: architecture

I'm studying system software, and have a little question.

When instruction format is 3 or 4, to make immediate addressing mode in SIC/XE machine the flag bits 'n' and 'i' should be n=0 & i=1. But in this mode, are x/b/p/e bits always 0? or are these bits converted into addressing bits?

Shortly, I am curious that in immediate addressing mode, what is the range of the value. is it 2^12 or 2^16?

Resolved:
I checked this table: http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~stremler/2003_CS530/SicAddressing.html so xbpe flags aren't always 0, it depends on which addressing mode(direct addressing in format 3/4, PC relative, BASE relative).

Comment: You appear to be talking about one specific architecture ("SIC/XE" ?), which is not a common one. Do you mean  this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Instructional_Computer ? Note that this type of details are particular to each design, and will vary in real CPU's.